# load styles before javascript - webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

My JavaScript is loading before my styles, which is causing a jump and odd load.

Here is my demo: https://harp29.github.io/cb-pc/

How do I get the styles/css file to load before the JavaScript file runs via webpack? I tried `setTimeout` function and it works but this is a temporary solution, that is the best way to tackle this issue?

My webpack file: webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
// const cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: [
      "webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true",
      "./src/script/main.js"
    ]
  },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "dist",
    overlay: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "images/[name].[ext]"
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "html-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "pug-loader"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/pug/index.pug",
      title: "Cervini Bhatia PC",
      inject: true
    })
  ]
}
```

my main.js file:

```
const scss = require('../scss/style.scss');
import index from '../pug/index.pug';
import favicon from '../images/favicon.png';
import logoSymbol from '../images/logo-symbol.svg';
import IntroAnimations from './module/IntroAnimations';

//Instaniate
new IntroAnimations()
.animateTimelines();
```

my index.pug file:

```
doctype html
html
  head.
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome - Cervini Bhatia PC</title>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png">
  body   
    include ./modules/_loading.pug
    include ./modules/_landing.pug
    include ./modules/_team-section.pug
    include ./modules/_experience.pug
    include ./modules/_firm.pug
    include ./modules/_communication.pug
    include ./layout/_footer.pug
```

Comment: wait for the dom to be ready.

Comment: Hello.

yes, did but nothing happened - window.onload but no change. setTimeout worked but yeah..

Comment: Please also add your `../pug/index.pug` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest fix would be to include a small bit of CSS in your pug template that hides the `<body>`. And then include a line of JS to unhide the `<body>` before your animations start.

---

EDIT: if you would like to load your CSS file separately from your JS bundle, use the https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin. In your template, include a `<link>` tag to the public path of your generated CSS file.

---

This is happening because you're bundling with style-loader, which puts your CSS as a string inside your Javascript bundle.

So the HTML will render (very fast) while the browser is parsing your JS bundle (very slow). Towards the end of that bundle, the browser will find the module containing your CSS string. Then it'll parse that and apply the styles with Javascript.

Comment: okay makes sense, is there a way to load css first via webpack? like add it into the link tag on its own in html?

Comment: You can add the `<link>` tag to the pug template, just like you would in HTML. How does the `IntroAnimations` module work?

Comment: its the animations for the start of the website - loading page and landing page transitions.

Comment: just saw.. my webpack is not generating a .css file into my dist folder.. umm how to fix this?

Comment: You can use the ExtractTextPlugin, https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage. Just replace "styles.css" in the example with what you want the CSS file to be called.

Comment: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

/Users/harpreetsingh/Desktop/Designs_by_harp/pc-cervini/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:712
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead

Getting these errors.

I think you have to use minicss-extract-plugin or so with webpack 4

Comment: Right, I forgot to ask which version of Webpack you're using. mini-css-extract-plugin looks like it'll work. Also, feel free to edit your questions with an updated Webpack config if you want more help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have [critical CSS](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/24/critical-css-webpack/) or "above the fold" CSS.

Since you are already using pug, you should take a look at the documentation for the HtmlWebpackPlugin.  They have an example of how to inline the `<style>`s you use that can be found here: [inline example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/examples/inline/template.jade).

The basic idea is that the template has access to `htmlWebpackPlugin.files` which has a `css` property that you can iterate and append as `<style>`s before the `<script>`s which blocks parsing until the styles are applied.

Make sure that you keep this critical CSS lean.  It "blocks", but this will be imperceptible as long as you don't inline a gigantic amount of CSS.

Comment: just saw.. my webpack is not generating a .css file into my dist folder.. umm how to fix this? Same way as you mentioned above?